# How can i customize xmlrpc response and request in python

Tags: python, xml-rpc, xmlrpclib

Here is my xmlrpc server python code.I want to change response.

```
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer
import logger
import db_connect

# Set up logging
logger.Logger(name="rpc", address="rpc.log")

server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(('0.0.0.0', 4242), logRequests=True)

# Expose a function
def get_status(extension):
  status=db_connect.get_status(extension)
  logger.logger().info(" extension number  %s Found %s 
   ",extension,status )
    return status

  server.register_function(get_status)

try:
   print ('Use Control-C to exit')
   server.serve_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
   print ('Exiting')
```

Xml rpc server return the following response to the client.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<methodResponse>
  <params>
    <param>
    <value><boolean>0</boolean></value>
    </param>
  </params>
</methodResponse>
```

Is it possible to return customize response like below?

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<Status>
<Extension>605</Extension>
<Bite_Status>Operational Fault</Bite_Status>
<Iridium_Channels_Available>0</Iridium_Channels_Available>
<DND_State>Disabled</DND_State>
<DND_Override>Disabled</DND_Override>
<Mute_State>Disabled</Mute_State>
</Status>
```

Also want to change http header response status code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return multiple, potentially nested elements from your xmlrpc server, have your function return a dictionary:

```
def status(ext):
    status = { 
        'Extension': 605,
        'Bite_Status': 'Operational Fault',
        'Iridium_Channels_Available': 0,
        'DND_State': 'Disabled',
        'DND_Override': 'Disabled',
        'Mute_State': 'Disabled'
    }
    return status

server.register_function(status)
```

This will return the xml below; it's more verbose than you're example as it has to conform to the xmlrpc specification.  If you're using the standard library's [ServerProxy](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xmlrpc.client.html#serverproxy-objects) as your client the xml would be converted to a dictionary the same as that generated by the server function.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<methodResponse>
<params>
<param>
<value><struct>
<member>
<name>Extension</name>
<value><int>605</int></value>
</member>
<member>
<name>Bite_Status</name>
<value><string>Operational Fault</string></value>
</member>
<member>
<name>Iridium_Channels_Available</name>
<value><int>0</int></value>
</member>
<member>
<name>DND_State</name>
<value><string>Disabled</string></value>
</member>
<member>
<name>DND_Override</name>
<value><string>Disabled</string></value>
</member>
<member>
<name>Mute_State</name>
<value><string>Disabled</string></value>
</member>
</struct></value>
</param>
</params>
</methodResponse>
```

The status code is [hardcoded](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/db8707c8ab57d9454c838586c08199c82a3d74d9/Lib/xmlrpc/server.py#L532) in the server implementation, so it cannot be changed unless you write your own server.  Note also that a return code of 200 is required by the [xlmrpc specification](http://xmlrpc.scripting.com/spec.html) for successful responses.

Comment: Thank you for your response.I got a solution by creating a new request handler instance of `xmlrpc.server.SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler`.